# iOS 9 iCloud Drive not showing all my folders and files

Tags: icloud, ios

Now that iOS 9 lets you add attachments to email from iCloud Drive, I thought I'd give it a spin. I put some test files in a folder on iCloud Drive on my Mac, and then went to my phone and tried to add an attachment. I only see a couple folders from two apps, and my own folder I added isn't shown. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: This is happening for me as well. Looking for an answer.

Comment: It started working on its own. And magically, an iCloud Drive app got installed on my phone too, out of nowhere. Very strange.

Answer (score 1):

This should work. The only caveat I can discover is the that file you wish to attach in email must be *fully downloaded*. The download state of each file is visible in the iOS iCloud Drive app.